# How to Upload a file in Dotnet core 3.1 Web app

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, web-applications, asp.net-core-3.1

Actually I'm try to upload a file from user. But I'm getting error. I tried various way even the **Microsoft doc** also. I can't help myself. So please  help me

Link: [Microsoft Doc dotnet core 3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

My action :

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Updateperson(UpdatePersonViewModel updatePerson)
        {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string uniqueFileName = null;
                if(updatePerson.Photo != null)
                {
                    string[] words = updatePerson.Photo.FileName.Split('.');
                    int a = words.Rank;
                    uniqueFileName = words[a];
                    uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_." + uniqueFileName;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine("Images",uniqueFileName);

                    //string filePath = Path.Combine(config["Images"], uniqueFileName);
                    //  using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                    //        {
                    //           await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    //           }

                    await updatePerson.Photo.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Create));
                }
                _context.Persons.Update(updatePerson);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Profile", new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Profile", id = updatePerson.Id }));
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Profile", new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Profile", id = updatePerson.Id }));
            }


        }
```

**>>> config is a object of IConfiguration**

Here is Error:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means no such directory named **Image** exists!

You can simply check if it exists, or create one if it doesn't exist.

```
if(!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
}
```

To test:

Use a `directoryPath` variable like this:

```
var directoryPath=Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images");
```

Comment: It could be that the path to the directory is wrong. I edited my answer anyway.

Comment: In my wwwroot folder I created Images folder. I can't find the actual path

Comment: You shouldn't place images in wwwroot. That means you will download everything in your database for the user, every time. Just delete the folder and test the code.